# Let a user select the theme

Tags: 8

For a few weeks, I have been developing a site based on Drupal 8 and so far, everything's working fine. Only recently I found a functionality that I had expected to be there, but that now seems to be missing.

In a nutshell, I would like to allow registered users to select the site theme (out of a small pre-defined set). This was a functionality that I was present in Drupal 6, but that seems to have been dropped in Drupal 7 (see the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035972/drupal-7-how-can-you-set-a-theme-to-a-user) and the discussion [here](http://drupal.org/node/292253)). In that thread, the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module was suggested as an alternative, but that hasn't been ported to Drupal 8 yet. I also found two more modules ([Theme Change](https://www.drupal.org/project/theme_change) and [Clever Theme Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/clever_theme_switcher)) that are capable of changing themes in Drupal 8, but not based on a user selection.

So, lacking a suitable module (I'm open for suggestions, though), I guess I will have to implement this myself, maybe even code a simple module or extend the Clever Theme Switcher. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. Can anybody offer any help?

Comment: Are you sure Theme Change can't do it? It seems to have the permission to let the users choose their own, just set the entire site to it, without other conditions.

Comment: Ah, interesting idea. For some reason that thought didn't occur to me. Will do some tests and report back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, that module seems to be intended for a different purpose: After installing it becomes clear that it's actually called "Admin Theme Change" (so, it's misnamed on drupal.org) and the description says, "Changes admin theme for selected pages".

Comment: I do see the name and description are different, but maybe those are the wrong parts? Maybe it does work for the entire site?

Comment: In my opinion relying on multiple themes just to let users switch the look and feel of a site is overhead. Just offer them some form element, store the choice in a cookie or session variable and add a body class accordingly. This body class then can be used to style certain site elements differently.

Comment: @prkos: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the module, but found that it didn't provide any interface for end users. It's just a simple method for overriding themes on specific pages (or the whole site, but then not excluding, say, the admin pages). So, for what I need to do (allowing users to select a theme using a simple switch, as it was possible in D6) this seems unusable. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @leymannx: Thanks for the suggestion, that's a good idea. And it is, indeed, what I probably will need to do, unless I find a way to switch the themes. I kinda disagree about the overhead, though: Having to add countless CSS selectors for styling all the items on the page in two or three different colors would be worse than just switching the theme, I think.

Comment: You can decide to what elements you add the additional class. If the `<body>` tag is not enough add them wherever you want. Also with some CSS preprocessor like Sass you can get hold of parent selectors down the tree quite easily. But of course, as always, it depends. Good luck anyways. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in code by implementing [ThemeNegotiatorInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeNegotiatorInterface.php/interface/ThemeNegotiatorInterface/8.7.x). This is a tagged service, for which you can set a priority. So you can let [AdminNegotiator](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Theme%21AdminNegotiator.php/class/AdminNegotiator/8.7.x) (priority -40)  choose the theme first, before you set the theme for non admin pages, but no later than -100, the priority of [DefaultNegotiator](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21DefaultNegotiator.php/class/DefaultNegotiator/8.7.x).